# Automatic creation of subtitles from an audio track

Tags: video, audio, subtitles

Is there a tool that allows you to create (using, for example, "AI") subtitles by using audio track in a video? YouTube, for example, has such a feature. It takes the original audio and automatically creates subtitles. I need something similar but for my PotPlayer. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a little detail such as which spoken language(s) you would like it to support?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [auto-subtitle](https://github.com/m1guelpf/auto-subtitle) CLI app. It uses Whisper under the hood, so a bunch of different models for various languages are usable. `large` are the most accurate ones, but also the slowest.

E.g.

```
auto_subtitle input.mp4 --model large -o output.mp4
```